# Merging two tags within a parent context

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT transformation to perform some functions on a data set. I have an input xml file:

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Tag>
            <Key>20</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>23</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>61</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>61</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>30</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Tag>
            <Key>20</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>23</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>61</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>61</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>30</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

This represents a set of Messages that get passed around the system. In this example, the Tag Keys: `20`, `23`, and `30` only exist once, however, Tag Keys `60` and `61` have an unbounded number of occurrences. These Tags are related to each other, and the relationship is based on proximity (i.e. the `61` proceeding a `60` is related to that Tag). The Tag Key `61` is also not mandatory, so a `60` could exist without a related `61` proceeding it.

So, what I am trying to do is combine those Tags together to get a form such as:

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Tag>
            <Key>20</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>23</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
            <RelatedBody>...</RelatedBody>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
            <RelatedBody>...</RelatedBody>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>30</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Tag>
            <Key>20</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>23</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
            <RelatedBody>...</RelatedBody>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>60</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
            <RelatedBody>...</RelatedBody>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>30</Key>
            <Body>...</Body>
        </Tag>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

So, how can I transform in XSLT each Message to combine a `60` with a (optionally, as seen in the 2nd `60` in Message 2) proceeding `61`?

Thanks

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you mean a `Key[.='61']` _preceding_ or _following_ the `Key[.='60']` element? It would also help to have text content other than "..." to tell where a text node came from. Finally, you forgot to post your XSLT code.

Answer (score 2):

Any XSLT problem that starts "I want to keep most of the XML the same but tweak X and Y" should generally start with an identity template, which copies the input XML unchanged except where overridden with more specific behaviour

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With that in place you can then add more specific templates for the things you want to change.  First off, you could remove all the `Tag` elements with `Key` 61 using

```
<xsl:template match="Tag[Key = '61']" />
```

Now for the key 60 tags, you appear to want to copy them as-is, but if they are *immediately* followed by a 61 then insert an extra element.  You can do this quite succinctly using template modes

```
<xsl:template match="Tag[Key = '60']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="related"
          select="following-sibling::*[1][self::Tag][Key = '61']" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Tag" mode="related">
  <RelatedBody><xsl:value-of select="Body" /></RelatedBody>
</xsl:template>
```

The magic here is in the `select="following-sibling::*[1][self::Tag][Key = '61']"`, which will select the element immediately following this one, but *only* if that element is a `Tag` with key 61.  If there is no following element, or if it isn't a `Tag` with key 61, then the expression will select nothing.